# How to enumerate Areas in ASP.NET MVC 2 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas, areas

My controller has to enumerate all the areas in the application. Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From this issue](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=5252), something like that =>

```
RouteTable.Routes.OfType<Route>()
            .Where(r => r.DataTokens != null)
            .Select(r => (string) r.DataTokens["area"]);
```